# Plot the Kampyle of Eudoxus with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I wish to generate the Kampyle of Eudoxus with Gnuplot:

```
plot x*x*x*x = x*x + y*y
```

This code should do the trick. However, it returns me the following error:

```
plot x*x*x*x=x*x+y*y
            ^
"file.plt", line 1: unexpected or unrecognized token
```

Is there a way to plot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [gnuplot FAQs](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/index.html#x1-450005.2) you will find a note that you cannot plot implicit defined graphs directly, however, a workaround is described.

Default `samples` is 100. So, in order to increase precision `set samples 1000` and `set isosamples 1000`.

**Script:**

```
### plot implicit graph
reset session

f(x,y) = x**4 - a*(x**2 + y**2)
a = 1

set samples    1000
set isosamples 1000
set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.0
unset surface
set table $CONTOUR
    splot f(x,y)
unset table
set key top center

plot $CONTOUR w l lc "red" ti sprintf("\n\nKampyle of Eudoxus\nx^4 = a*(x^2 + y^2)\na = %g",a)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]